# UNIX bash - How to compare values from the same column?

Tags: command-line, scripts, text-processing

I have a file where I would like to compare if each set of 4 values from column 2 are equal.

This is part of my `input.txt` file:

```
1        493733  
2        493733  
3        493733  
4        493733  
1        546328  
2        546328  
3        546328  
4        546328
```

I need a script to compare the values on column 2 from the first 4 rows:

```
1        493733  
2        493733  
3        493733  
4        493733
```

Then jump to the next 4 rows (...until the end of the file - length might vary):

```
 1        546328  
 2        546328  
 3        546328  
 4        546328
```

The numbers on column 2 are supposed to be the same every 4 rows but sometimes there is a different one that i need to catch.

If the numbers match, output some kind of message. If any of those numbers do not match, output in a `.log` file to be checked.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48520216/unix-bash-how-to-compare-values-from-the-same-column

Comment: Your requirements are not clear.

Comment: Hi Glenn, let me try to shortly explain again. I need a script to compare the value of row 1 column 2 against the value of row 2 column 2... and so on for the 4 rows where the values are supposed to be the same. I would have to put it in a loop to scan the entire file, always comparing the values of the 4 rows.

Comment: Please put updates in question not comment

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```sh
file="input.txt"
log_file="some.log"

num_lines=$(wc -l < "$file")
for i in `seq 0 $(bc<<<$num_lines/4)`; do
    FIRST_LINE=$(bc<<<"$i*4+1")
    SECOND_LINE=$(bc<<<"$i*4+2") 
    if [ "$(awk NR==$FIRST_LINE "$file")" == "$(awk NR==$SECOND_LINE "$file")" ];
    then
        echo "some kind of message"
    else
        echo "Lines $FIRST_LINE and $SECOND_LINE do not match" | tee -a "$log_file"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Since the numbers are all integers, you could use Bash math `$((...))` instead of `bc`.